# Question about an infinite sum in which every term is infinite

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Given the sequence $x_k=\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{kn^2}$ where $k\in\Bbb{N}$, define an infinite sum $S=x_1-x_1+x_2-x_2+x_3-x_3+...$

Now every $x_k$ is infinite, but does $S=0$? I know we cannot say $S=0$ but I don't understand why.

$S$ can be rearranged as $S=(x_1-x_1)+(x_2-x_2)+(x_3-x_3)+...$ 
If we just look at the symbols, does not $x_1-x_1=0$, $x_2-x_2=0$, ... always because the minuend and subtrahend are identical? Why they cannot hold when $x_k$ is infinite?

Comment: That $S$ definition is somewhat ambiguous... Try defining appropriate sequence $(S_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of partial sums of some sequence, then ask about the limit $S=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}S_n$.

Comment: A series (or sequence) doesnt hold any value. Maybe you mean the "sum" of the series, that is a limit.

Comment: Can you do $-x_1+x_2$ in the first place?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly my confusion. Different arrangement gets different result.

Comment: Does this mean this kind of sum is meaningless and cannot be defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sum $S$ is not well defined.  As you say none of the terms in it are well defined.  You can get the same behavior from well defined series that are convergent, but not [absolutely convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).  A series is absolutely convergent if the series formed by taking the absolute value of all the terms is still convergent.  So if we have the series $\log 2 = 1-\frac 12 + \frac 13 -\frac 14 \dots$.  We know the harmonic series $1+\frac 12 + \frac 13 +\frac 14 \dots$ diverges so if we sum the terms from $\log 2$ in a different order we can get any answer we want.  Yes, this says that for non-absolutely convergent series your intuition is not correct.  Often our experience with finite objects (like sums) is not correct when we make the transition to infinite objects (like series).

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer to this question is that you can't add/subtract infinities. Infinity is really just a concept to help us understand when a term grows arbitrarily large under certain conditions. In this case it means the function has no finite limit as you vary the argument in the given range. It's conventional, and intuitive, to write $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = \infty$. But the limit doesn't actually *equal* anything, it just means the function value grows and grows, and passes every imaginable value in the process.

So to deal with the slippery concept of infinity, try what CiaPan suggested in the comment and take the limit outside the series. So now we have $x_k= \frac{1}{kn^2}$ (no limit) and the series is:

$S= \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} (x_1-x_1+x_2-x_2+x_3-x_3+...)$ and from here you could factor out the $n$ from the sum because it's independent giving:

$\lim_{n \rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{n^2}(1-1+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+...)$

Now, the infinite series converges to $0$ because the partial sums are either equal $0$ or they are equal $\frac{1}{k}$ for arbitrarily small $k$. And so the limit in $n$ also goes to $0$

Of course, this is just one way to remove the ambiguity and the infinities. Another way would be to take the limit over every two consecutive terms i.e.

$S= \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} (x_1-x_1) + \lim_{n \rightarrow 0} (x_2-x_2) + \lim_{n \rightarrow 0}(x_3-x_3) +... = \\ 0 + 0 + 0 + ... = 0$.

These are arguably the more "obvious" or "intuitive" interpretations of your series. This is why you intuitively *feel* that the series should sum to zero. But this example is a good demonstration of the fact that when dealing with the infinite, great care is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You might group terms in different manner, possibly getting different result:

$S=x_1+(-x_1+x_2)+(-x_2+x_3)+(-x_3+x_4)+\dots$

Try making your $S$ definition more precise.

Comment: Yes. That's my confusion. Different arrangement gets different result.

Comment: @Tony So don't 'arrange' but rather make a precise definition what sequence you are summing.

Answer (score 1):

For any $k \in \Bbb N,$ we have that
$$ x_k = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0}\frac1{kn^2} = + \infty $$

Hence the expression $x_1 - x_1$ is undefined, since $(\infty - \infty)$ is not defined in the extended reals. Note also that $x_i = x_j$ for any $i,j \in \Bbb N,$ since the value of each of the limits are the same.

If we instead define $x_k$ to be a function however, given by $x_k(n) = 1/kn^2,$ then we have that,
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow 0} (x_1(n) - x_1(n)) = \lim_{n\rightarrow 0}(0) = 0.$$

The main issue is that in general, swapping limits gives different values. This is especially an issue with working with divergent sequences and series.

The topic of rearrangement is a different issue, which CiaPan has address with his comment of how you need to define the partial sums. I'm going to give another example of this though, since this can also arise in the case of finite terms. Consider the series,
$$ 1 - 1 + 1 -1 + 1 -1 + \dots $$
If we define the partial sums as $s_n = \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^n,$ then $(s_n)$ does not converge, since it alternates between $0$ and $1.$ However if we instead define it as $s_n' = \sum_{i=0}^n (1-1),$ then it is easy to see that the partial sums are all $0$ and hence the series converges to $0.$

Comment: ...and if you exclude the first term from the sum operator: $s^{''}_n = 1 + \sum_{i=1}^\infty(-1+1)$ then the result will be $1+0+0+0+\ldots=1$.